# Error adding package: 'No git executable was found'

Tags: c#, git, unity-game-engine, openai-api, package-managers

I've been trying to add the OpenAI-Unity 'https://github.com/srcnalt/OpenAI-Unity' package to my project but I am receiving this error: *Cannot perform upm operation: Unable to add package [https://github.com/srcnalt/OpenAI-Unity.git]: No 'git' executable was found. Please install Git on your system then restart Unity and Unity Hub [NotFound].*

I added the path to Git to my environment variables and tried

C:\Program Files\Git\cmd 
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\Git.exe 
C:\Program Files\Git\bin 
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\Git.exe

..but nothing worked. I also restarted the editor and unity hub but it kept giving me the same error! The editor version I am using is 2021.3.15.
Does anyone have any fixes to this?

Thank y'all for reading

Comment: How did you install git?  Did you modify the user or system path environment variable? (Presumably it shouldn't matter I guess.)  Can you run git commands in a command prompt or shell?  Btw, the readme https://github.com/srcnalt/OpenAI-Unity#supported-unity-versions-for-webgl-builds does say that version 2021.3.5 is not supported, though I would assume that wouldn't prevent you adding it as a package.

Comment: @AndrewMcClement Thank your for your response. I installed Git via the link on the Unity documentation, https://git-scm.com/download/win. I modified the system path ev. With the Git\bin and Git\cmd I can run commands on the shell, however Git\bin\Git.exe and Git\cmd\Git.exe do not work.

Comment: I rebooted my computer and now everything is working !